# nullpointerException where getting models using ebeans relations in playframework

Tags: java, playframework, models, ebean

I need to get all events connected to a user.

I created a model to handle this relation:

```
@Entity
public class Affiliated extends Model{

@OneToMany
private Bruker bruker;
@OneToOne
private Event event;
@Column(nullable = false)
private Calendar alarmTime = null;

public enum Status{
    ATTENDING, MAYBE, NOT_ATTENDING, UNDECIDED
}

private Status status;

public Affiliated(){
    this.status=Status.UNDECIDED;
}

public static Finder<Event, Affiliated> find = new Model.Finder<Event, Affiliated> (
       Event.class, Affiliated.class
);
```

I have tried to do this:

```
 public static Result getEvents(){
    if(Bruker.signedIn()) {
        List<models.Event> eventList = models.Event.find.where().eq("creator", Bruker.find.byId(session("User"))).findList();
        List<Affiliated> affiliatedList = models.Affiliated.find.where().eq("bruker", Bruker.find.byId(session("User"))).findList();
        for (Affiliated i : affiliatedList) {
            eventList.add(i.getEvent());
        }
        return Bruker.signedIn(ok(views.html.layoutHtml.render("MyEvents", views.html.Event.myEvents.render(eventList))));
    }
    return redirect(routes.Application.index().absoluteURL(request()));
}
```

But it returns a `nullpointerException` for `affiliatedList` when I try to run it, even though there should be no problem returning an empty list.

Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

ps: "bruker" means "user" in norwegian.

Comment: do you have sql logs on?Check the query created?

Comment: Hmm, i have no experience with sql logging, googling it now, will update when i find out how

Comment: @brax94 How do you access Affiliated fields if they are private??

Comment: there are getters and setters. Didn't think to post them as well :)

Comment: Have got some logs now, output is 4 distinct statements, 3 that selects all from Bruker where username = "myusername" and one that selects all fields from Event where event_creator = "myusername"..
This is not what i want it to return anyway, so ill need to rethink my query..